# TSQL SP Query Fails to Execute After 24 Hours Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Long story sort, we have a fairly intensive SQL query that is used for grids with filtering, sorting, pagination, etc. It searches about 150,000 application type records. The SPs is fairly timely, generally taking about 2 - 3 seconds to handle a filter search, etc. However a strange issue happens about every 1 - 3 days. The SP itself seems to lock up and not return any results for any filter, sort, or page parameter passed to it. A simple fix is to do an alter statement, not change any of the SQL itself and execute the alter on the SP. It then seems to free up whatever is blocking it and it will run for another 1 - 3 days. Obviously we can't keep resaving the SP every 3 days or so. We did add OPTION (RECOMPILE); to the end of the SP and that helped, but the problem still happens every 5 - 7 days or so. Basically my question is, what would cause this lockup on the SP? A little more info, when the lockup happens, only this SP is unresponsive, all other queries and SPs run smoothly with no noticeable latency. Other than the one SP not working the entire DB runs fine, there is no CPU spike or memory issue. We are also running the latest version of SQL server.

I can't show the entire query but the WHERE statement looks something like this for the query filter. It involves a lot of wildcard LIKE statements on a series of joined tables.

```
WHERE
        (@Query is null 
            OR  concat(p.First , ' ' , p.Last) LIKE '%' + @Query + '%' 
            OR  concat(j.First , ' ' , j.Last) LIKE '%' + @Query + '%'
            OR  concat(p.First , ' ' , p.Middle , ' ' , p.Last) LIKE '%' + @Query + '%' 
            OR  concat(j.First , ' ' , j.Middle , ' ', j.Last) LIKE '%' + @Query + '%'
```

Comment: When the procedure takes a long time, SQL Server can tell you why. Always check `sys.dm_exec_requests` for potential blocking (`blocking_session_id`) and `sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats` for what it's been waiting on the most.

Comment: Do you have querystore enabled on the database? You can check if there are multiple plans and force a regression if necessary etc. Very likely, given your query snippet, your query needs a refactor to take performance and concurrency into consideration. Dynamic SQL might help you here.

Comment: 150K very little  data but the query is certainly very inefficient. It can't use any indexes on the fields the question shows which means it needs to scan *all* of them. This will easily lead to widespread blocking and possibly deadlocks, as the shared locks taken on all rows will prevent modifications

Comment: Conditions like the one shown can't use any indexes. No index can help look in the middle of a field. That's why all applications use `StartsWith` conditions. `FirstName Like 'A%` is essentially a range search `FirstName >='A' and FirstName < 'B'` which *can* use indexes. Instead of all those concatenations you could write `FirstName Like @term +'%' or LastName like @term + '%' or MiddleName like @term+'%'`.

Comment: Almost certainly this is a [parameter sniffing problem](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html). To diagnose this, we need at a minimum: the *full* query, the tables *and indexes* involved, and please share the fast and slow query plans via https://pastetheplan.com. Without this we cannot help.

Comment: But even if the query has to scan the entire table every single time, making the query more efficient (even if there are supporting indexes and that still covers the expected semantics), it doesn't change 2-3 seconds -> 24 hours. That's not "slower query", that's stuck.

Comment: Another option which, unfortunately, won't help with names, is to create a [Full Text Search index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) and use operators like `CONTAINS` to find words, phrases and their variations in text fields. FTS searches whole words or phrases though, not parts of a name

Comment: @AaronBertrand we don't know what else is running that could take exclusive locks on that table. That snippet is guaranteed to lock the entire table

Comment: If you really want such partial searches, it may be a better idea to use eg Elastic/OpenSearch. Elastic uses very different indexing strategies to search for strings inside other strings

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Right, but my point is, locking an entire table (150K rows) sometimes takes 2-3 seconds, so if it suddenly takes 24 hours, it's unlikely that the exact same query is taking 28,000 times longer simply because there's an inefficient predicate that locks the entire table (since the 2-3 second version had that too!). It is more likely there is something else _preventing_ it from taking those locks. We can all guess but we can _know_ if they are able to capture wait/blocking information as I suggested.